# PrimeNG inputs with formgroup that contains other formgroups

Tags: angular, primeng

After some day of research, without a solution. I explain my problem, so i have a primeNG input like this:

```
<p-autoComplete [formControl]="formInput" [suggestions]="postalCodesSuggested" [minLength]="minimumLengthForAutoComplete" [inputStyleClass]="class" (completeMethod)="onComplete($event)"></p-autoComplete>`
```

When i select or just write a value in the autocomplete, the formControl is not filled..

The "formInput" variable that is passed to the [formControl] is a control inside a formGroup itself in a formGroup like this:

```
    this.formIput = this.builder.group({
        address: this.builder.group({
          postalCode:[posLocalisation.type.argument],
          city:[],
          street:[]
        }),
    });
```

Other autoComplete inputs with simple formGroup works like a charm, so i presume that formGroup is the problem. Can anyone have a solution ?

Thanks in advance,
Uak

Comment: Did you try to use `FormControl` for that instead of `FormGroup`?

Comment: the formInput variable is already a formControl, but the architecture of the formGroup is more advanced that a simple formGroup that just contains formControl

Comment: Do you see any errors? Something like `control.registerOnChange is not a function` `FormGroup` doesn't have such method. You have to pass `FormControl` here `[formControl]="formInput"`

Comment: i've no error in the console. input never modifie the control so, the control is always equals to ""